# vercel Deployment has failed

Tags: next.js, newline, vercel

my project in on nextjs
when i pushed the code on github then their shows an red cross

I tried on terminal. It compile successfully and no error their but when i check on github it shows a red cross build deployment filed

this is the command i entered on terminal

PS C:\Users\we\lazycodelab> npm run build

> lazycodelab@0.1.0 build
> next build
> info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\we\lazycodelab.env
> warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
> warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
> info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
> info  - Compiled successfully
> info  - Linting and checking validity of types ...warn  - The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config
> info  - Linting and checking validity of types .Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .
> info  - Linting and checking validity of types
> info  - Collecting page data
> info  - Generating static pages (7/7)
> info  - Finalizing page optimization
> Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
> ┌ ○ /                                      22.1 kB        90.9 kB
> ├ ○ /blog                                  185 B          79.3 kB
> ├ λ /blog/[slug]                           186 B          79.3 kB
> ├ ○ /career                                2.03 kB        81.1 kB
> ├ ○ /privacy                               3.22 kB          72 kB
> └ ○ /terms                                 7.42 kB        76.2 kB

- First Load JS shared by all              68.8 kB
  ├ chunks/455-81a868d820ddd3dc.js         66.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-52af883dc7aa679d.js    203 B
  └ chunks/webpack-540d6077ea747753.js     2.2 kB
  Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
  ─ ○ /404                                   179 B          84.7 kB
- First Load JS shared by all              84.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-4bf5ec8de43dddb4.js        82.1 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-907dedfd0e4177db.js  192 B
  └ chunks/webpack-540d6077ea747753.js     2.2 kB
  λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
  ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
  info  - Creating an optimized production build ..

here is the pic of github
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ5hb.png)